# Seeed studio Grove IMU 9DOF gyro reading denoising

Tags: gyroscope, accelerometer, stability, noise

Using this IMU (https://wiki.seeedstudio.com/Grove-IMU_9DOF-lcm20600+AK09918/), I am having an issue with the gyro readings. Seems like the reading comes with lots of noise. Could anyone help me to find a way how to denoise the readings? I am operating the device in low power mode for both the gyro and accelerometer. I am pasting sample output for gyro and accelerometer below.

The accelerometer has another problem. it often outputs a very big value, e.g.,-124.946756 for the X-axis. I was thinking to apply a filter as described here (https://www.instructables.com/Guide-to-gyro-and-accelerometer-with-Arduino-inclu/). But with this issue with the accelerometer reading, I am not sure if the filter would even work.

By the way, I took an average of 1000 samples during initialization and subtract it from the readings for both the gyro and accelerometer to offset any bias and the device was resting while reading the values.

**Gyro readings:**

```
Gyro reading: X,Y,Z is 0.000461 rps, 0.003013 rps, 0.001052 rps
Gyro reading: X,Y,Z is 0.001526 rps, -0.002310 rps, -0.005336 rps
Gyro reading: X,Y,Z is -0.001668 rps, -0.000181 rps, -0.002142 rps
Gyro reading: X,Y,Z is 0.000461 rps, 0.001948 rps, -0.000013 rps
Gyro reading: X,Y,Z is -0.000604 rps, -0.002310 rps, -0.004272 rps
Gyro reading: X,Y,Z is -0.002733 rps, -0.000181 rps, -0.003207 rps
Gyro reading: X,Y,Z is 0.001526 rps, -0.002310 rps, 0.002116 rps
Gyro reading: X,Y,Z is -0.002733 rps, 0.000884 rps, -0.002142 rps
Gyro reading: X,Y,Z is -0.000604 rps, -0.003375 rps, -0.002142 rps
Gyro reading: X,Y,Z is -0.001668 rps, 0.001948 rps, -0.001078 rps
Gyro reading: X,Y,Z is -0.002733 rps, 0.004078 rps, -0.000013 rps
Gyro reading: X,Y,Z is -0.002733 rps, 0.000884 rps, 0.001052 rps
Gyro reading: X,Y,Z is -0.001668 rps, -0.000181 rps, -0.000013 rps
Gyro reading: X,Y,Z is 0.001526 rps, -0.000181 rps, -0.002142 rps
Gyro reading: X,Y,Z is -0.000604 rps, -0.000181 rps, -0.000013 rps
Gyro reading: X,Y,Z is -0.001668 rps, -0.001246 rps, -0.003207 rps
Gyro reading: X,Y,Z is -0.003798 rps, 0.004078 rps, 0.003181 rps
Gyro reading: X,Y,Z is 0.001526 rps, 0.001948 rps, -0.000013 rps
Gyro reading: X,Y,Z is 0.001526 rps, -0.001246 rps, 0.001052 rps
Gyro reading: X,Y,Z is 0.002590 rps, 0.000884 rps, -0.000013 rps
Gyro reading: X,Y,Z is -0.000604 rps, -0.004440 rps, 0.001052 rps
Gyro reading: X,Y,Z is 0.000461 rps, 0.000884 rps, -0.000013 rps
Gyro reading: X,Y,Z is -0.000604 rps, -0.001246 rps, 0.002116 rps
Gyro reading: X,Y,Z is -0.002733 rps, -0.003375 rps, -0.003207 rps
Gyro reading: X,Y,Z is -0.000604 rps, -0.000181 rps, 0.002116 rps
Gyro reading: X,Y,Z is -0.003798 rps, 0.000884 rps, 0.004246 rps
Gyro reading: X,Y,Z is -0.001668 rps, -0.002310 rps, -0.000013 rps
Gyro reading: X,Y,Z is -0.001668 rps, -0.001246 rps, -0.004272 rps
Gyro reading: X,Y,Z is 0.000461 rps, 0.003013 rps, -0.000013 rps
Gyro reading: X,Y,Z is -0.003798 rps, 0.000884 rps, -0.002142 rps
Gyro reading: X,Y,Z is 0.000461 rps, 0.001948 rps, 0.001052 rps
Gyro reading: X,Y,Z is -0.001668 rps, -0.000181 rps, -0.004272 rps
Gyro reading: X,Y,Z is -0.001668 rps, -0.002310 rps, -0.000013 rps
Gyro reading: X,Y,Z is -0.000604 rps, 0.000884 rps, -0.002142 rps
Gyro reading: X,Y,Z is -0.001668 rps, -0.002310 rps, -0.002142 rps
Gyro reading: X,Y,Z is -0.000604 rps, 0.004078 rps, -0.001078 rps
Gyro reading: X,Y,Z is 0.000461 rps, 0.003013 rps, -0.000013 rps
Gyro reading: X,Y,Z is 0.000461 rps, 0.003013 rps, 0.001052 rps
Gyro reading: X,Y,Z is 0.001526 rps, -0.000181 rps, -0.003207 rps
Gyro reading: X,Y,Z is 0.000461 rps, 0.006207 rps, 0.003181 rps
Gyro reading: X,Y,Z is -0.000604 rps, 0.000884 rps, -0.001078 rps
Gyro reading: X,Y,Z is 0.003672 rps, -0.002310 rps, -0.003207 rps
Gyro reading: X,Y,Z is -0.001668 rps, 0.000884 rps, 0.002116 rps
Gyro reading: X,Y,Z is 0.000461 rps, -0.000181 rps, 0.002116 rps
Gyro reading: X,Y,Z is -0.000604 rps, -0.001246 rps, -0.000013 rps
Gyro reading: X,Y,Z is 0.002590 rps, -0.003375 rps, -0.001078 rps
Gyro reading: X,Y,Z is 0.001526 rps, 0.003013 rps, 0.272695 rps
Gyro reading: X,Y,Z is 0.001526 rps, 0.001948 rps, -0.001078 rps
Gyro reading: X,Y,Z is -0.003798 rps, -0.000181 rps, -0.001078 rps
Gyro reading: X,Y,Z is 0.001526 rps, -0.001246 rps, -0.004272 rps
Gyro reading: X,Y,Z is -0.000604 rps, -0.000181 rps, -0.003207 rps
Gyro reading: X,Y,Z is 0.001526 rps, -0.000181 rps, -0.001078 rps
Gyro reading: X,Y,Z is -0.002733 rps, 0.000884 rps, 0.001052 rps
Gyro reading: X,Y,Z is -0.003798 rps, 0.004078 rps, 0.001052 rps
Gyro reading: X,Y,Z is 0.002590 rps, -0.001246 rps, -0.003207 rps
Gyro reading: X,Y,Z is 0.001526 rps, -0.001246 rps, -0.000013 rps
Gyro reading: X,Y,Z is -0.000604 rps, 0.000884 rps, -0.000013 rps
Gyro reading: X,Y,Z is 0.000461 rps, 0.000884 rps, -0.004272 rps
Gyro reading: X,Y,Z is 0.001526 rps, -0.000181 rps, 0.005310 rps
Gyro reading: X,Y,Z is -0.001668 rps, -0.005504 rps, -0.003207 rps
Gyro reading: X,Y,Z is 0.001526 rps, -0.001246 rps, -0.002142 rps
Gyro reading: X,Y,Z is 0.002590 rps, 0.000884 rps, -0.006401 rps
Gyro reading: X,Y,Z is 0.000461 rps, 0.003013 rps, -0.000013 rps
Gyro reading: X,Y,Z is -0.001668 rps, -0.000181 rps, 0.001052 rps
Gyro reading: X,Y,Z is -0.001668 rps, -0.002310 rps, -0.000013 rps
Gyro reading: X,Y,Z is -0.000604 rps, 0.001948 rps, -0.001078 rps
Gyro reading: X,Y,Z is 0.004737 rps, -0.000181 rps, -0.001078 rps
Gyro reading: X,Y,Z is -0.001668 rps, -0.000181 rps, -0.001078 rps
Gyro reading: X,Y,Z is -0.003798 rps, -0.001246 rps, -0.006401 rps
Gyro reading: X,Y,Z is -0.000604 rps, -0.003375 rps, 0.001052 rps
Gyro reading: X,Y,Z is 0.001526 rps, -0.000181 rps, 0.002116 rps
Gyro reading: X,Y,Z is -0.002733 rps, 0.000884 rps, -0.003207 rps
Gyro reading: X,Y,Z is -0.002733 rps, -0.000181 rps, 0.001052 rps
Gyro reading: X,Y,Z is -0.001668 rps, 0.000884 rps, 0.002116 rps
Gyro reading: X,Y,Z is -0.000604 rps, 0.000884 rps, -0.000013 rps
Gyro reading: X,Y,Z is -0.002733 rps, -0.000181 rps, -0.001078 rps
Gyro reading: X,Y,Z is 0.000461 rps, -0.000181 rps, 0.003181 rps
Gyro reading: X,Y,Z is 0.002590 rps, -0.002310 rps, -0.004272 rps
Gyro reading: X,Y,Z is 0.002590 rps, 0.000884 rps, 0.004246 rps
Gyro reading: X,Y,Z is 0.001526 rps, -0.003375 rps, -0.000013 rps
Gyro reading: X,Y,Z is -0.001668 rps, 0.000884 rps, -0.001078 rps
Gyro reading: X,Y,Z is 0.002590 rps, 0.003013 rps, -0.003207 rps
Gyro reading: X,Y,Z is -0.001668 rps, 0.001948 rps, 0.002116 rps
Gyro reading: X,Y,Z is 0.001526 rps, 0.000884 rps, 0.002116 rps
Gyro reading: X,Y,Z is -0.002733 rps, 0.003013 rps, -0.006401 rps
Gyro reading: X,Y,Z is 0.001526 rps, 0.001948 rps, 0.002116 rps
Gyro reading: X,Y,Z is -0.000604 rps, 0.001948 rps, -0.004272 rps
Gyro reading: X,Y,Z is -0.000604 rps, -0.002310 rps, 0.002116 rps
Gyro reading: X,Y,Z is 0.000461 rps, 0.001948 rps, -0.002142 rps
Gyro reading: X,Y,Z is -0.000604 rps, 0.000884 rps, 0.001052 rps
Gyro reading: X,Y,Z is -0.001668 rps, -0.002310 rps, 0.001052 rps
Gyro reading: X,Y,Z is -0.000604 rps, 0.001948 rps, 0.002116 rps
Gyro reading: X,Y,Z is 0.001526 rps, 0.000884 rps, -0.000013 rps
Gyro reading: X,Y,Z is -0.000604 rps, -0.001246 rps, -0.002142 rps
Gyro reading: X,Y,Z is 0.002590 rps, -0.002310 rps, -0.000013 rps
Gyro reading: X,Y,Z is -0.002733 rps, -0.001246 rps, -0.003207 rps
Gyro reading: X,Y,Z is -0.000604 rps, 0.000884 rps, -0.000013 rps
Gyro reading: X,Y,Z is -0.000604 rps, -0.000181 rps, 0.001052 rps
Gyro reading: X,Y,Z is 0.001526 rps, -0.001246 rps, -0.001078 rps
Gyro reading: X,Y,Z is 0.001526 rps, 0.003013 rps, 0.001052 rps
Gyro reading: X,Y,Z is -0.005927 rps, -0.001246 rps, -0.001078 rps
Gyro reading: X,Y,Z is 0.000461 rps, 0.004078 rps, -0.000013 rps
Gyro reading: X,Y,Z is -0.002733 rps, -0.000181 rps, -0.003207 rps
Gyro reading: X,Y,Z is 0.000461 rps, 0.000884 rps, -0.000013 rps
Gyro reading: X,Y,Z is 0.002590 rps, -0.000181 rps, 0.001052 rps
Gyro reading: X,Y,Z is 0.001526 rps, 0.001948 rps, -0.003207 rps
Gyro reading: X,Y,Z is -0.000604 rps, -0.002310 rps, -0.002142 rps
Gyro reading: X,Y,Z is 0.000461 rps, 0.001948 rps, -0.001078 rps
```

**Accelerometer readings:**

```
Accel reading: X,Y,Z is -1.899756 mg, -4.213442 mg, -1.828915 mg
Accel reading: X,Y,Z is -5.805756 mg, -1.772442 mg, -0.363915 mg
Accel reading: X,Y,Z is -6.294756 mg, 2.621558 mg, 1.101085 mg
Accel reading: X,Y,Z is -6.294756 mg, -2.260442 mg, 0.124085 mg
Accel reading: X,Y,Z is 1.518244 mg, -0.307442 mg, -0.851915 mg
Accel reading: X,Y,Z is 0.053244 mg, -3.237442 mg, 1.589085 mg
Accel reading: X,Y,Z is -1.411756 mg, 2.133558 mg, -5.734915 mg
Accel reading: X,Y,Z is -124.946756 mg, 2.621558 mg, -1.339915 mg
Accel reading: X,Y,Z is 5.424244 mg, -0.795442 mg, 0.613085 mg
Accel reading: X,Y,Z is -1.411756 mg, 3.598558 mg, 2.078085 mg
Accel reading: X,Y,Z is -6.294756 mg, -0.795442 mg, -0.363915 mg
Accel reading: X,Y,Z is -5.317756 mg, -2.749442 mg, -3.293915 mg
Accel reading: X,Y,Z is 0.053244 mg, 2.133558 mg, -0.851915 mg
Accel reading: X,Y,Z is -3.364756 mg, -2.260442 mg, -0.851915 mg
Accel reading: X,Y,Z is -4.829756 mg, 1.645558 mg, 2.566085 mg
Accel reading: X,Y,Z is -3.852756 mg, 0.180558 mg, -1.828915 mg
Accel reading: X,Y,Z is 1.030244 mg, 1.645558 mg, 0.124085 mg
Accel reading: X,Y,Z is 0.541244 mg, 3.598558 mg, 1.101085 mg
Accel reading: X,Y,Z is 2.494244 mg, -0.307442 mg, 1.101085 mg
Accel reading: X,Y,Z is -0.923756 mg, 2.133558 mg, -2.316915 mg
Accel reading: X,Y,Z is -2.387756 mg, 0.668558 mg, -1.339915 mg
Accel reading: X,Y,Z is -0.923756 mg, 0.180558 mg, -2.316915 mg
Accel reading: X,Y,Z is 1.030244 mg, 1.157558 mg, 1.101085 mg
Accel reading: X,Y,Z is 2.494244 mg, -2.749442 mg, 3.542085 mg
Accel reading: X,Y,Z is -4.341756 mg, -3.725442 mg, 2.078085 mg
Accel reading: X,Y,Z is 2.494244 mg, 3.110558 mg, -2.804915 mg
Accel reading: X,Y,Z is 1.030244 mg, 1.157558 mg, -0.851915 mg
Accel reading: X,Y,Z is -1.411756 mg, -0.795442 mg, 0.124085 mg
Accel reading: X,Y,Z is -3.364756 mg, -0.307442 mg, -0.363915 mg
Accel reading: X,Y,Z is -2.876756 mg, 3.598558 mg, -1.339915 mg
Accel reading: X,Y,Z is 0.541244 mg, 1.645558 mg, -0.363915 mg
Accel reading: X,Y,Z is -4.829756 mg, 4.575558 mg, 0.124085 mg
Accel reading: X,Y,Z is -123.481756 mg, 1.645558 mg, -2.804915 mg
Accel reading: X,Y,Z is 0.053244 mg, -2.749442 mg, -0.363915 mg
Accel reading: X,Y,Z is -4.829756 mg, -0.795442 mg, 1.101085 mg
Accel reading: X,Y,Z is -2.387756 mg, -0.307442 mg, -1.828915 mg
Accel reading: X,Y,Z is -0.434756 mg, -0.307442 mg, 2.078085 mg
Accel reading: X,Y,Z is -1.411756 mg, -0.307442 mg, 3.054085 mg
Accel reading: X,Y,Z is 0.053244 mg, 2.621558 mg, -3.781915 mg
Accel reading: X,Y,Z is -2.876756 mg, -0.795442 mg, 0.124085 mg
Accel reading: X,Y,Z is 1.518244 mg, -0.795442 mg, -1.339915 mg
Accel reading: X,Y,Z is -3.364756 mg, 3.598558 mg, 2.078085 mg
Accel reading: X,Y,Z is -3.364756 mg, -0.307442 mg, 1.101085 mg
Accel reading: X,Y,Z is 2.006244 mg, 0.668558 mg, -0.363915 mg
Accel reading: X,Y,Z is -1.899756 mg, -1.284442 mg, -0.363915 mg
Accel reading: X,Y,Z is -0.434756 mg, -6.167442 mg, 0.124085 mg
Accel reading: X,Y,Z is 124.565244 mg, 2.621558 mg, 0.613085 mg
Accel reading: X,Y,Z is -3.364756 mg, 2.133558 mg, -1.828915 mg
Accel reading: X,Y,Z is 2.006244 mg, 2.133558 mg, 1.589085 mg
Accel reading: X,Y,Z is 1.518244 mg, -2.260442 mg, -0.363915 mg
Accel reading: X,Y,Z is -3.852756 mg, 1.157558 mg, 0.124085 mg
Accel reading: X,Y,Z is -3.364756 mg, -3.237442 mg, 3.542085 mg
Accel reading: X,Y,Z is -1.411756 mg, 0.180558 mg, 0.124085 mg
Accel reading: X,Y,Z is -3.364756 mg, 1.157558 mg, 4.519085 mg
Accel reading: X,Y,Z is -1.899756 mg, 1.645558 mg, -0.363915 mg
Accel reading: X,Y,Z is -124.458756 mg, 3.110558 mg, -1.339915 mg
Accel reading: X,Y,Z is 1.518244 mg, -2.749442 mg, -2.316915 mg
Accel reading: X,Y,Z is -0.923756 mg, -1.772442 mg, 3.542085 mg
Accel reading: X,Y,Z is -1.411756 mg, 3.598558 mg, -1.828915 mg
Accel reading: X,Y,Z is -0.434756 mg, 1.157558 mg, 4.519085 mg
Accel reading: X,Y,Z is 1.030244 mg, 3.110558 mg, -0.363915 mg
Accel reading: X,Y,Z is -0.434756 mg, 3.598558 mg, -3.293915 mg
Accel reading: X,Y,Z is -1.411756 mg, -2.260442 mg, -1.339915 mg
Accel reading: X,Y,Z is 120.658244 mg, -1.284442 mg, 1.101085 mg
Accel reading: X,Y,Z is -4.341756 mg, 2.621558 mg, -1.828915 mg
Accel reading: X,Y,Z is -3.364756 mg, 2.133558 mg, -1.828915 mg
Accel reading: X,Y,Z is 2.494244 mg, 2.621558 mg, 1.589085 mg
Accel reading: X,Y,Z is -0.434756 mg, -3.237442 mg, 0.613085 mg
Accel reading: X,Y,Z is -0.434756 mg, 1.157558 mg, 0.124085 mg
Accel reading: X,Y,Z is -0.434756 mg, -1.772442 mg, -1.339915 mg
Accel reading: X,Y,Z is -3.852756 mg, -0.307442 mg, -3.293915 mg
Accel reading: X,Y,Z is -124.458756 mg, -0.307442 mg, -1.828915 mg
Accel reading: X,Y,Z is -2.387756 mg, 2.621558 mg, -1.339915 mg
Accel reading: X,Y,Z is -1.899756 mg, -3.237442 mg, -0.363915 mg
Accel reading: X,Y,Z is 2.983244 mg, 1.645558 mg, -3.293915 mg
Accel reading: X,Y,Z is -1.411756 mg, 5.063558 mg, 1.589085 mg
Accel reading: X,Y,Z is -124.458756 mg, -2.260442 mg, 1.589085 mg
Accel reading: X,Y,Z is -3.852756 mg, -0.795442 mg, -4.269915 mg
Accel reading: X,Y,Z is -4.341756 mg, 0.180558 mg, -1.828915 mg
Accel reading: X,Y,Z is 1.030244 mg, 0.180558 mg, -3.293915 mg
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.